# What's the technical name of the captcha like thing which asks you to identify all the 'ice-cream' pictures?

Tags: spam-prevention, validation

What is the technical name of that class of tool that pops up 5 to 6 images and asks you to pick all the 'xyz' items from that list? `CAPTCHA` is text on a funny background and you are asked to read that text and type it as an answer to unlock some part of the web-site - this however is asking you to identify some subset of images as verification you are a human.

[image]
<sub>(source: [kym-cdn.com](http://i3.kym-cdn.com/photos/images/newsfeed/000/963/262/259.png))</sub>

Comment: AFAIK it's just another _type of_ CAPTCHA - a system used to determine whether a user is a human. A "picture CAPTCHA", "picture classification CAPTCHA"? I have not heard of a "technical" (or "official") name for this type of captcha?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This kind of spam prevention is usually provided by the [reCAPTCHA service](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/intro/index.html#) from Google. IMHO this is an advanced spam protection service based on the principles of CAPTCHA. While I do not think reCAPTCHA is a technical name and there could also be other advanced implementations of CAPTCHA-like spam protection.